# Swift - How to get selected segment of control embedded in a UITableView cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UITableView in a UIViewController. There are two custom cells. One of these has a UISegmentedControl.

[image]

So far, so good.

When I tap the control,  the segmented control value changes and IBAction function runs as expected.

The problem is that the selected index always shows as -1, (aka nothing selected).

What am I missing here?

Here is the code for the value change:

```
 @IBAction func recurranceChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl?) {

        print ("index: ", recurrenceControl.selectedSegmentIndex) << This returns -1

        if recurrenceControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            print("No ")
        }

        if recurrenceControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
            print("Sometimes ")

        }


        if recurrenceControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
            print("Yes")

        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using `sender` rather than `recurrenceControl`?

Comment: That's it.. If you want to make it an answer, I'll close this out.. BTW.. For others, the code should be `sender?.selectedSegmentIndex`

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question. "BTW", in action methods, you have no need to use Optional, declare the parameter as `sender: UISegmentedControl` (no `?`) and use as `sender.selectedSegmentIndex`.

Comment: Great. double thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: (Also removed the '?' from UISegmentedControl as it isn't needed.)

```
@IBAction func recurranceChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    print ("index: ", sender.selectedSegmentIndex)

    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        print("No ")
    }

    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        print("Sometimes ")

    }


    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
        print("Yes")

    }

}
```

this should solve the problem ;)

Comment: even you can get the title by " segment.titleForSegment(at : indexValue)"

Answer (score 1):

So I don't know if the answer/question is done in just a static tableview or by adding an IBAction to a customCellController but this doesn't work that well. For example, reusing a cell across multiple tableviews (My case) will cause either too many if statements in the cell controller (e.g. for each table view) or cause the app to crash.

Another approach to this is, adding a target to `SegmentedControl` in each cell

**Swift 5**

**CustomCell.swift**

```
@IBOutlet weak var mSC: UISegmentedControl!
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     //
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "textCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
     cell.mSC.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.onSegChange(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
 }


//This function is called when the segment control value is changed
@objc func onSegChange(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    //REPLACE tableview to your tableview var
    let touchPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.tableview)
    let tappedIndexPath = tableview.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint)

    print("SECTION: \(tappedIndexPath!.section)")
    print("ROW #: \(tappedIndexPath!.row)")
    print("SEG CON INDEX: \(sender.selectedSegmentIndex)")
    print("Tapped")
```

}

I know this question is older but I hope this helps someone down the road like me.